# How to test a Step in a FlowJob

Tags: spring, junit, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I'm attempting to test a Step contained within a Flow, contained in within a Job. Here's the basic Job configuration:

```
    Flow readFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("readFlow").start(step01.deleteProcessedRecords()).on("*")
            .to(step02.retrieveIdentifiers())...end();

    Flow firstWriteFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("firstWriteFlow").from(step04.createFirstFile()).end();


    FlowJobBuilder builder = new JobBuilder("createFiles").repository(jobRepository)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(readFlow)
            .on("*")
            .to(firstWriteFlow)
            .end();
```

I will make the flows more complex, they have been simplified for the sake of example. When I execute the following test I get an error:

```
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("runId", "Step01").toJobParameters();


    JobExecution exec = jobLauncherTestUtils
            .launchStep("deleteProcessedRecords", jobParameters);
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Step found with name: [deleteProcessedRecords]
```

However, if I test the Job, the step is clearly there:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("runId", "Step01").toJobParameters();


    JobExecution exec = jobLauncherTestUtils
            .launchJob(jobParameters);
```

success:

```
2016-05-09 17:34:47.387  INFO 16748 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=createFiles]] launched with the following parameters: [{runId=Step01}]
2016-05-09 17:34:47.450  INFO 16748 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [deleteProcessedRecords]
2016-05-09 17:34:47.699  INFO 16748 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [retrieveIdentifiers]
```

I've checked the documentation [for Unit Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting) which seem to indicate I should just be able to pass in the Step name. Can anyone show me how to properly test a Step or if I'm doing something incorrectly? Thanks in advance,

Sergio.

EDIT:

As requested, here's the step:

```
@Autowired
private DeleteProcessedRecordsTasklet deleteProcessedRecordsTasklet;

@Bean
public Step deleteProcessedRecords() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("deleteProcessedRecords")
            .tasklet(deleteProcessedRecordsTasklet)
            .build();
}
```

I am using spring-batch-core version 3.0.7.RELEASE, part of spring-boot-starter-batch 1.3.5.RELEASE

Comment: please add the code from step01.deleteProcessedRecords()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I would comment instead of answering, but I don't have enough reputation.  But depending on your Spring batch version, you might be affected by this [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2291).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the POM, I am using spring-boot-starter-batch version 1.3.3.RELEASE, which uses spring-batch-core 3.0.6.RELEASE, so it should've already been resolved. I will try to upgrade to the latest and greatest, see what happens.

Comment: same result, unfortunately.

Comment: can't recreate the issue. I'll just mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you today and I hope this can help you.

My problem was that the flows were not initialized by the time that I was trying to launch the step, therefore the step could not be found:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Step found with name: [firstStep]

To Solve my issue I simply marked with the @Bean annotation the functions that return my Flows, this way the Flows are initialized before I try to launch the step using JobLauncherTestUtils.

```
@Bean //***this solved my problem***
public Flow initialFlow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("initialFlow")
    .start(firstStep)
    .next(secondStep)
    .end();
}
```

Now I am able to run the step like this:

```
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(exampleJob);
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("firstStep");
```

I figured it out by placing a break point on [this file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/f4c05307301970cd04086f3d1aa59953ea53fea5/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/FlowJob.java) inside the function `findSteps`. I realized that the step was not being added to the map of steps that is used by the `getStep` method(which is used by the `launchStep` from `JobLauncherTestUtils`).

My problem was not related to [bug 2291](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2291) and I suspect yours is not either. If you are using 3.0.7.RELEASE you already have the code for the fix.